# Comparison between two two-dimensionla arrays

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to find best way to comparise two two-dimensional arrays and write elements which there aren't in first array.

In case of one-dimensional array all is easy:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [1, 2, 3]
newArray = list(set(b) - set(a))
```

`newArray` in this case will be `[3]`

Difficults in this case. For example, I have:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 5], [4, 6, 9]]
b = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 5], [2, 6, 5]]
```

and I want to get `newArray = [[1, 4, 5], [2, 6, 5]]`, but if I try `newArray = list(set(b) - set(a))` it leads to error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How I can realize as same as in case of one-dimensional array? Length of arrays may be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert the lists into a format that's hashable, e.g. `tuple`:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 5], [4, 6, 9]]
>>> b = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 5], [2, 6, 5]]
>>> set(map(tuple, b)) - set(map(tuple, a))
set([(2, 6, 5), (1, 4, 5)])
```

If the result shall be a list of list, you can convert the tuples back afterwards.

```
>>> list(map(list, set(map(tuple, b)) - set(map(tuple, a))))
[[2, 6, 5], [1, 4, 5]]
```

---

Like your original approach, this has complexity of O(n+m), n and m being the length of the lists, making it somewhat faster than the nested list comprehension which uses repeated lookup in lists, which has O(n) as opposed to lookup in sets with O(1), but it also comes with some overhead for conversion to tuples, creating the sets, etc. Whether its *actually* faster, and whether that's worth the more complex code, may depend on the size of the lists.

If the lists are short, e.g. 10 elements, the list comprehension is in fact a tiny bit faster than using `map` and `set`, and *quite* a bit faster than `map` and `set` and conversion back to `list`:

```
>>> a = [[randint(0, 3) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(10)]
>>> b = [[randint(0, 3) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(10)]
>>> %timeit [x for x in b if x not in a]
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.8 us per loop
>>> %timeit set(map(tuple, b)) - set(map(tuple, a))
100000 loops, best of 3: 14 us per loop
>>> %timeit list(map(list, set(map(tuple, b)) - set(map(tuple, a))))
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.8 us per loop
```

If the lists are longer, though, say 1000 elements, then using `set` becomes *much* faster.

```
>>> a = [[randint(0, 10) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(1000)]
>>> b = [[randint(0, 10) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(1000)]
>>> %timeit [x for x in b if x not in a]
10 loops, best of 3: 82.5 ms per loop
>>> %timeit set(map(tuple, b)) - set(map(tuple, a))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.16 ms per loop
>>> %timeit list(map(list, set(map(tuple, b)) - set(map(tuple, a))))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.43 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach, but answer of Henry Woody is easiest. Am I right that this method is more faster than `[x for x in b if x not in a]`?

Comment: @SBrain As so often, the answer is "it depends". See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to iterate through `b` and return lists that are not in `a`. Here's an example:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 5], [4, 6, 9]]
b = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 5], [2, 6, 5]]
new_array = [x for x in b if x not in a]
```

And `new_array` is equal to:

```
[[1, 4, 5], [2, 6, 5]]
```

Comment: Note that this has complexity O(n*m) which may be prohibitive for very long lists; for short lists, though, this is certainly okay, shorter and more readable than using `set`.

Comment: Yeah the time complexity of this method means it shouldn't be used if `a` and `b` or their contents get large, but for reasonably small cases I think the simplicity of the code makes it worth it.